# Shifted My magento 2 store from local server to AWS

Tags: php, installation, apache, aws

I am new to `aws` and uploaded my current magento2 store also have done the installation process regarding apche 2 php, mysql and phpmyadmin installation also installed composer in root directory now when I enter the magento root directory it is displaying me it as

[image: ss]

So What should I do to connect it with database

Comment: check the webserver-logs. there should be more information on why there's a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Please can you share the steps or procedures to hit the required URL? Meanwhile, purge cache and check for the server logs to identify why are you getting this error.

Also, look for the PHP and MySQL versions just in case.